# Not able to identify iPad Pro devices by using Javscript

Tags: javascript, ios, user-agent, device-detection

I am trying to identify iPad devices by using various methods in JS. As per the latest research on this, newer versions of iPad Pro behaving same as desktop versions(Same user agent). Since both iPad and Mac shows same user agent details, it's very difficult to differentiate iPad and Mac devices.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually there are better ways to design your responsive site/app than trying to identify the particular device. For more details you can refer to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
var isIPadPro = /Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent) && 'ontouchend' in document;
```

Comment: This solution gives false value in iPad. Any other methods?

Comment: Here you can find some methods to try: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/289359